# I don't understand what's wrong with this simple Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I wrote this program to ask users for their age, and then tell them how old they will be in 10-50 years. I don't understand what's wrong with it :( I'm just a beginner and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
print "How old are you?"

age = gets.chomp
i = 1

while i < 6
multiple = i * 10 + age
puts "In #{multiple} years you will be #{multiple}"
i++
end
```

Comment: age is coming through as a string, not a num so you're doing `i * 10 * string`.  In the future your question should include the output of your program and the desired output

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as ++ in Ruby. Use i += 1. And read about indent style.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When creating a question, it's important to create a title for it that actually indicates what you are trying to do. That helps us answer your question by understanding what you're after, and it helps others who are searching for a similar solution. "I don't understand what's wrong with this simple Ruby code" does absolutely nothing toward either of those. Remember, the more work you put into creating the question, the more likely it is you'll get help and will avoid getting down votes. Also, when asking, explain what's wrong and how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. Make sure you're indenting blocks correctly - it'll make your code much more readable. Note that `to_i` converts your input from a String to an Integer. Also, try to name your variables more specifically; `multiple` doesn't really mean anything in your example.

```
puts "How old are you?"

age = gets.chomp.to_i

(1..5).each do |i|
  years_passed = i * 10
  new_age = years_passed + age
  puts "In #{years_passed} years you will be #{new_age}"
end
```

If you want to use a `while` loop, you could do:

```
puts "How old are you?"

age = gets.chomp.to_i
multiplier = 1

while multiplier <= 5
  years_passed = multiplier * 10
  new_age = years_passed + age
  puts "In #{years_passed} years you will be #{new_age}"
  multiplier += 1
end
```